# How to kill a running process using ANT in MAC?

Tags: java, ant, process, kill

I currently use ANT to trigger my java script. I want to know is there a way where I can close(kill) my application using ANT once it has completed the run.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Java script"; there may be a process invoking a JVM. Please paste the relevant section(s) of your `build.xml` along with the command line you use to run it, and the code of your `main(à`